# error "test_input_xml: input file not opened or empty" when run quantum espresso examples

Tags: runtime-error

I install *quantum espresso 6.2* and use *cygwin*. 
I run example01 to test quantum espresso, which calculate energy and band structure for Si, Al, Cu and Ni. I get an error message as follows:

```
running the scf calculation for Si...from test_input_xml: input file not opened or empty
At line 1999 of file read_namelists.f90 (unit = 9, file = 'input_tmp.in')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
from test_input_xml: input file not opened or empty
At line 1999 of file read_namelists.f90 (unit = 9, file = 'input_tmp.in')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

Could you help me to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What is PARA_PREFIX in your environment_variables file set to?

Try running with

```
PARA_PREFIX=" "
```

or if you have MPI you can try

```
PARA_PREFIX=" mpirun -np 1 "
```

Most tests and examples are meant to be run serially.

Comment: I think environment variables were set correctly. The messages are
 'This example shows how to use pw.x to calculate the total energy and the band structure of four simple systems: Si, Al, Cu, Ni.  
executables directory: /home/Namnt/quantumespresso6.2/qe-6.2/bin  
pseudo directory:      /home/Namnt/quantumespresso6.2/qe-6.2/pseudo  
temporary directory:   /home/Namnt/quantumespresso6.2/qe-6.2/tempdir
  checking that needed directories and files exist... done '

Comment: 'running pw.x as: mpirun -np 4 /home/Namnt/quantumespresso6.2/qe-6.2/bin/pw.x  -nk 1 -nd 1 -nb 1 -nt 1        
running the scf calculation for Si...from test_input_xml: input file not opened or empty'

Comment: Have you compiled with an MPI? mpirun invokes MPI. In your environment_variables try setting PARA_PREFIX=" ".
Check what it says in "QE folder"/install/configure.msg near the end. Parallel or serial configuration?

Comment: My problem is solved. Thank @Marculius a lot. I check the file configure.msg first and it says "Parallel environment not detected \(is this a parallel machine?\).\
Configured for compilation of serial executables." Then, I see near the end of environment variables file, there are two lines PARA_PREFIX=" "
 PARA_PREFIX="mpirun -np 4". I delete the second line to set PARA_PREFIX=" " and the problem is gone.